# Where can I find reliable documentation for creating Capistrano tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm at a loss trying to find reliable documentation for creating Capistrano tasks on an application that I'm trying to upgrade. I've tried to find documentation on

[Capistrano Docs](http://capistranorb.com/)

[Hungry and Foolish Writing Capistrano tasks](http://vladigleba.com/blog/2014/04/10/deploying-rails-apps-part-6-writing-capistrano-tasks/)

[Rails Cast Capistrano Task](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=del2AU0_yZ0)

and some wikis that are generally unhelpful or provide snippets of capistrano tasks. I know that Capistrano version 3 is based off Rake file syntax but what I want to do is to find a list of keywords/commands so I can rewrite pre-written Capistrano tasks from an earlier version. Links or resources would be much appreciated. Thanks.

*I am working on an application that has been using Capistrano 1.6 and now I need to upgrade to 3. The tasks are written, all I need to do is translate it into Cap 3.